# TCP avoid delayed acknowledge

Tags: tcp, network-programming

I'm having an application on a micro controller with a small TCP/IP stack. This application waits for a connection on a specific TCP port. As soon as the TCP connection is established the micro controller need to send 8 KB of data. Because the TX buffer of the TCP socket is only 1 KB tall I will need to send 8 segments of data. The TX buffer size can't be changed!

But now I have the problem, that after every segment a delay of 200 ms occurs. I know that this is caused by the delayed ack (which is on Windows 200 ms). But in my use case this means the whole process includes 1400 ms of delay time, which is just wasted time.

Is there any possibility that I can force the PC to acknowledge the data instantly (maybe a bit in the TCP header)? I can't change anything on the PC side.

Or should I instead sent two 512 byte tall segments instead of the 1 KB segment? Would this fix / trick out the issue? I have read that the PC will acknowledge the data if a second segement arrives.

What is the right way to solve such a usecase?

Comment: It was shown in the 1980s that TCP needs a send buffer of at least 4K. Are you sure this can't be changed? 1K is incredibly small for a device that sends 8K at a time. Design mistake here.

Comment: @user207421 Unfortunately I can't increase the send buffer. My available memory ressources are limited. Maybe a design mistake but I can't change it.

Comment: You should try disabling Nagle using socket option TCP_NODELAY.  If it is on, it will wait until the previous segment is acked before sending another partial frame, just like what you are seeing (note that a 1000 byte payload is typically less than a full frame of 1500 bytes with a 1460 byte payload).  If your stack is so primitive that you can't disable Nagle you could try to reduce the MTU from 1500 to 1040 so you can send a full frame and not have to wait for an ack to send another.